# Destroy not destroying after delay

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi I am currently learning from the book (Learning c# by developing games with unity 2021).

1.Right now in the game I have created a bullet object this object is supposed to be destroyed after being created.
2.But since I want to display it in the scene for a time I created a floating point to see how much time I can give. I applied these are parameters in the destroy utility function.

problem:-

1.Instead of destroying it after a certain time it deleted it entirely after it was created.
This is a problem the code I wrote to create the bullet is attached to my player.

2.It deletes the prefab in the starting of the game itself

Player action:-

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerBehavoiur : MonoBehaviour
{
    //this is a bullet made and used
    public GameObject Bullet;
    //the speed with the bullet
    public float BulletSpeed = 100f;
    //checks if our player is shooting
    private bool _isShooting;
    //stores the desired distance to ground
    public float distanceToGround = 0.1f;
    //creates a reference variable of type layermask
    public LayerMask GroundLayer;
    //gets the collider stored in a variable that will be used to access it
    private CapsuleCollider _col;
    void Update()
    {
        /*MoveForward(_hInput1);
        RotateUpWards(_vInput1);
        */
        _isJumping |= Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space);
        PrintIfJumping(_isJumping);
        //this sets it to a method that checks if the key in the 
        //arguments pressed down on 
        IsFalling |= Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.G);
        //scans for mouse input and sets the isShooting field to that value
        //if that value is true or when the mouse is clicked then run the shoot method
        //this is through prefabs which are are used
        _isShooting |= Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0);
    }
    void PrintIfJumping(bool _isJumping)
    {
        if (_isJumping == true)
        {
            Debug.Log("Time to take a leap of faith!");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Im on the ground this sucks!");
        }
    }
    void Start()
    {
        _rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        _rb.useGravity = true;
        //sets isJumping to keycode.space which checks wether the key space is pressed
        //gets the collider component and stores inside a variable for later use
        _col = GetComponent<CapsuleCollider>();
    }
    void SetVerticalDirection()
    {
        _vInput1 = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * MoveSpeed;
    }
    void SetHorizontalDirection()
    {
        _hInput1 = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * RotateSpeed;
    }
    public float MoveSpeed = 10f;
    public float RotateSpeed = 75f;
    public int hp = 0;
    /// <summary>
    /// stores a rigidbody component for a gameobject
    /// </summary>
    private Rigidbody _rb;
    public float JumpVelocity = 5f;
    private bool _isJumping;
    private bool IsFalling;
    public float FallVelocity;
    /// <summary>
    /// Start is called before the first frame update
    /// </summary>
    private float _hInput1;
    private float _vInput1;
    /// <summary>
    /// Update is called once per frame
    /// </summary>
    /*public void MoveForward(float _vInput)
    {
        _vInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * MoveSpeed;
        this.transform.Translate()
    }
    public void RotateUpWards(float _hInput)
    {
        _hInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * RotateSpeed;
        this.transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * _hInput * Time.deltaTime);
    }
    */
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        SetVerticalDirection();
        SetHorizontalDirection();
        //makes the object move by horizontal input in the up direction
        Vector3 rotation = Vector3.up * _hInput1;
        /*this is the rotation of the game object 
         * moving up and then going at a fixed frame rate
         */
        Quaternion angleRotation = Quaternion.Euler(rotation * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        //this takes vertical input and addes the position and makes it move forward
        //the vertical input is the vertical axis whihc moves at a defined rate tht we can define
        _rb.MovePosition(this.transform.position + 
            this.transform.forward * _vInput1 * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        /*the move rotation moves using the rigibody rotation times the 
         * horizontal input times and moves up and rotates at the rotate speed rate
         */
        _rb.MoveRotation(_rb.rotation * angleRotation);
        //performs a jump if object is in collision with ground and isJumping
        if(IsGrounded() && _isJumping)
        {
            /*while(JumpVelocity > 0)
            {
                --JumpVelocity;
            }
            */
            _rb.AddForce(Vector3.up * JumpVelocity, ForceMode.Impulse);
        }
        Fall(IsFalling);
        Shoot(_isShooting, Bullet);
    }
    private bool IsGrounded() {
        //this defines the bottom of the capsule or the end
        Vector3 capsuleBottom = new Vector3(_col.bounds.center.x, _col.bounds.min.y, _col.bounds.center.z);
        //this checks if a object is touching start or bottom of a capsule and the raduis is distance to ground
        //this sets the ground layer to the phy-system
        bool grounded = Physics.CheckCapsule(_col.bounds.center, capsuleBottom, distanceToGround, GroundLayer, QueryTriggerInteraction.Ignore);
        return grounded;
    }
    public void Fall(bool grounded)
    {
        bool Gpressed = Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.G);
        Debug.Log("G is pressed");
        Debug.LogFormat("The down direction is {0}", Vector3.down);
        if (Gpressed ==true & grounded == false)
        {
            _rb.AddForce(Vector3.down * FallVelocity, ForceMode.Impulse);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("No falling allowed!");
        }

    }
    public void Shoot(bool _isShooting,GameObject Bullet)
    {
        if (_isShooting == true)
        {
            //this is the instance of the prefab bullet which is created using the unity editor
            //builds 
            GameObject newBullet = Instantiate(Bullet, this.transform.position + new Vector3(1, 0, 0), this.transform.rotation);
            //create a new bullet rigidbody which captures the component rb
            Rigidbody BulletRB = newBullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
            //set the velocity (speed x direction) basically
            //so we want our bullet to go forward x a certian speed so...
            BulletRB.velocity = this.transform.forward * BulletSpeed;
        }
        _isShooting = false;
    }
    /*Horizontal: ad
     * Vertical: ws     */
}
```

Its pretty long I know just read the shoot function and the stuff in update on shooting

So the bullet behaviour is:-

```
public class BulletBehaviour : MonoBehaviour
{
    float OnScreenDelay = 3f;
    void Start()
    {
        Destroy(this.gameObject,OnScreenDelay);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
    public void Scale(float x, float y, float z)
    {
        this.transform.localScale = new Vector3(x, y, z);
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you move the `Destroy()` into the Player script instead so after setting the velocity simply call. `Destroy(newBullet, OnScreenDelay);`

Comment: Are you sure, you have **dragged and dropped** the **Bullet prefab** to the **GameObject Bullet** field on the **PlayerBehaviour** inside the scene?

Comment: Any chance that the field `OnScreenDelay` got reset to `0` in the bullet prefab's inspector?